# ReactJS + Redux - Material-UI: How to make <Toolbar/> floatable?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

Using: http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/toolbar , how can I make  floatable when scrolling down?

I was able to do it with  with the following:
`textAlign:'center', position: 'fixed', top: 0`
but when I do it with the `<Toolbar/>`, it resizes weirdly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the width to 100%? This worked for me:

```js
<Toolbar
  style={{
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    width: '100%'
  }}>
// Content
</Toolbar>
```

Or:

```js
<Toolbar
  style={{
    position: 'fixed',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
  }}>
// Content
</Toolbar>
```